# Customize msiexec progress bar?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, command-line-interface, windows-installer

My application call msiexec to run uninstall.

```
   logger->LogDebug("Actions: MsiUninstallExec()!");
    System::Diagnostics::Process ^p = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process();
    p->StartInfo->FileName = "msiexec";
    p->StartInfo->Arguments = "/x " + AppSetting::ProductCode;
    p->Start();
/// -->>> Uninstall
/// -->> Choose restart or not.
/// -->>> Application Exit
```

When uninstallation is done, users have to choose restart or not to complete this process.
But my customer request : "The progress bar of msiexec must move to the last (right end)." 
How to edit it ? Do you have any idea for me?

[image]

Comment: MSIEXEC is an external program that you have launched via the Process. You cannot control its ProgressBar from your C# code.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea for me to resolve this request ?

Comment: Do you just want to suppress the prompt and let the progress bar show uninstall progress, or do you want to hide all progress bars? What does that message say btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Suggestion***: You can try something like this ([find product GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup)):

```
msiexec.exe /X {PRODUCT-GUID} /QN REBOOT=ReallySuppress /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"
```

***Quick command line explanation***:

```
 /X {PRODUCT-GUID}          = run uninstall sequence for specified product 
 /QN                        = run completely silently
 /REBOOT=ReallySuppress     = suppress reboot prompts
 /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"  = verbose logging at specified path
```

---

***Alternatives***: There are many ways to invoke MSI uninstall: [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933). You can uninstall via: **`msiexec`**, **`ARP`**, **`WMI`**, **`PowerShell`**, deployment Systems such as **`SCCM`**, **`VBScript`** / COM Automation, **`DTF`**, or via **`hidden Windows cache folders`**, and a few other options.

---

***msiexec.exe***: There are two flavors of the **`msiexec.exe`** command line. An original one and a later one that added the "full word" switches such as `/quiet` and `/noreboot` and the likes. The original command line used `/qn` as the switch for silent mode. Here are links to both flavors: [MSIEXEC what is the difference between qn and quiet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450330/msiexec-what-is-the-difference-between-qn-and-quiet/17450760#17450760).

---

***Some Links***:

- [Silent installation of a MSI package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560166/silent-installation-of-a-msi-package)
- [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup)
- [How to report msi installation status on quiet install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947909/how-to-report-msi-installation-status-on-quiet-install)

Answer (score 0):

```
msiexec /passive /x ProductCode
```

This should give you just the ProgressBar UI. You can also ask the user whether they want to skip restart or always force restart when the Uninstall completes. Then can add the **/norestart** or **/forcerestart** option appropriately.